# JS addEventListener not all events are captured

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

```
    var fired = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (fired === false) {
        fired = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
          let cartItem = document.getElementsByClassName('jstore-js-cart-total-count')[0];
                        let countItem = cartItem.textContent;
                        let cartCloudCount = document.getElementsByClassName('sc_layouts_cart_items_short')[0];
                        cartCloudCount.textContent = countItem
                        cartItem.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
                            let countItem2 = cartItem.textContent;
                            let cartCloudCount2 = document.getElementsByClassName('sc_layouts_cart_items_short')[0];
                            cartCloudCount2.textContent = countItem2
                        });
        }, 100)
    }
});
```

I have a listener to catch events for adding to the cart.
But for some reason it works only for one product, if you work with one product, then it successfully changes the quantity, but if you add the second, then nothing changes, what's the problem?

Comment: `[0]`  A single product makes sense, if your only ever looking at the first one.

Comment: Is there no better option than `DOMSubtreeModified` for an event?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas 
What else can you use?
A ready-made basket comes to me via api, the only thing I need is to get the number of items and display it in a cloud above the basket icon

Comment: So the answer would be "no" ;) The handler might be called quite often depending on the content of `cartItem` if you listen for any DOM tree changes. Imho that should be the last option, hence my question.